# Cannot Approve Pull Request on GitHub with GitKraken

Tags: github, gitkraken

I am using GitHub with an Organization. I'm trying to approve a **Pull Request** within **GitKraken** through the **GUI**. EVerything else works fine such as push, pull, etc. I get an error saying: "Failed to merge pull request. You may be using a private email. Try using your default email.".

I'm using the same email address from GitHub in my `~/.gitconfig` and GitKraken Login. Does anyone know what setting I have to change for this?

[image]

Comment: same for me definitely the same email as my default github email

Comment: Same for me. I used GitKraken to generate the SSH keys, I'm able to do everything but not merge a PR. The emails match.